# Jquery selector on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a jquery selector on an HTML line.

```
var render = "<div id=\"cellContainer\"></div>";
$(render).find("#cellContainer").append("this is a test");
$("#container").html(render);
```

For some reason it does not output anything. What am I missing ?

Edit: let me clearify that this is a simplification of my actual code so I'm not looking for alternative ways.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxN3n/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than doing that, you can simply:

```
$("<div />", {
    id: "cellContainer",
    html: "this is a test"
}).appendTo("#container");
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxN3n/4/).

I suggest you check out both http://learn.jquery.com and http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: Thank you, however the question is a simplification of my actual code. I can not use this approach since I have a more complex HTML

Comment: @Hazaart in that case could post up your actual code?

Comment: @Hazaart well you have several problems here. The main one being that `div` elements cannot be a child of `tr` elements, only `td` and `th` elements can. I've modified your code to firstly remove that `div` element altogether, giving your `tr` element the ID of "cellContainer"; secondly to wrap this as a jQuery object; and finally to add the `render` object to the `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ebhr3/20/